# Unable to restart Rabbitmq: badarg rpc.erl line 206

Tags: rabbitmq

My RabbitMQ server seems to be running all the connections from Celery are refused.

Here is my status:

```
(venv) root@xyz:/var/log/rabbitmq# sudo -u rabbitmq rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@xyz ...
[{pid,673},
 {running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.4.3"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.14"},
                        {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.5"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.3.4"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.19.4"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.16.4"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,"Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:2] [async-threads:30] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,[{total,40492248},
          {connection_readers,0},
          {connection_writers,0},
          {connection_channels,0},
          {connection_other,6856},
          {queue_procs,2704},
          {queue_slave_procs,0},
          {plugins,0},
          {other_proc,13684848},
          {mnesia,0},
          {mgmt_db,0},
          {msg_index,2263632},
          {other_ets,766920},
          {binary,2761320},
          {code,16179613},
          {atom,561761},
          {other_system,4264594}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,[]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,858993459},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,21639958528},
 {file_descriptors,[{total_limit,924},
                    {total_used,3},
                    {sockets_limit,829},
                    {sockets_used,1}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,106}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,1619146}]
```

Here is what I get when I try to restart:

```
root@xyz:/var/log/rabbitmq# sudo -u rabbitmq rabbitmqctl stop
Stopping and halting node rabbit@xyz ...
Error: {badarg,[{erlang,group_leader,[undefined,<5172.10942.32>],[]},
                {rabbit_log,with_local_io,1,[]},
                {rabbit,stop_and_halt,0,[]},
                {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                     [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,205}]}]}
```

Nothing outputs in the logs...

How can I restart my RabbitMQ server?

Comment: I manage to kill the process and restart with `service rabbitmq-server start`